# Анимация по движению мыши

Tags: javascript, css, анимация, css-animation, background

Ребят, приветствую!

Случайно зашёл на один сайт и увидел анимацию прикреплённую к движению мыши.

https://dolinger-web.ru/

Вот на это сайте.

Как можно это сделать?

Понимаю, что писать это в ответе будет очень долго и муторно, но если нет интереса и желания, напишите, пожалуйста, что почитать, чтобы реализовать этот эффект.

Заранее благодарю за ответы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут используется [WebGL](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API)

Забавно, но есть уже готовый урок по этому эффекту (только там левую кнопку мыши нужно держать зажатой)

- https://tildoshnaya.com/modification/colorsmoke

Comment: Спасибо за ответ)